# What is the value of a missing column of an INSERT in a BEFORE INSERT Trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-insert

Consider the following table

```
CREATE TABLE position (x INTEGER, y INTEGER, z INTEGER);
```

Now the following query

```
INSERT INTO position (x, y) VALUES (1, 2);
```

Question: – What is the value of `z` inside a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger for this query?

Comment: @lad2025 Is it guaranteed? If you could please give me a link to a document where this is explained in detail I will be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick demo: The value of z will be `NULL`:

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20a9e/1/0)**</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE position (x INTEGER, y INTEGER, z INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE position_temp (x INTEGER, y INTEGER, z INTEGER);

CREATE TRIGGER testref BEFORE INSERT ON position
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO position_temp(x, y, z) 
    VALUES (NEW.x, NEW.y, NEW.z);
  END;

INSERT INTO position (x, y) VALUES (1, 2);
```

If table has `DEFAULT` like:

```
CREATE TABLE position (x INTEGER, y INTEGER, z INTEGER DEFAULT 5);
```

You will get z = 5.

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d9f7/1/0)**</kbd>

More info in [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html). You should watch out `AUTO_INCREMENT`:

> In a BEFORE trigger, the NEW value for an AUTO_INCREMENT column is 0,
>   not the sequence number that is generated automatically when the new
>   row actually is inserted.

Comment: FYI: I had to add `DEFAULT NULL` to the column, which now makes me think that my question was silly.